# Read user email contents using imaplib2

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a python code to read email from mail server(neither google nor outlook) using imaplib2 package. I'm getting the following error with my code. Can anybody tell me how could I fix it. Do I need to use only port=993 and host=imap, if so how can I connect to the server I need to

```
import imaplib2
import base64
email_user = 'mailid'
email_pass = 'password'
email_server = 'ns21.interactivedns.com'

Mail = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL(email_server, 995) # used this server and port since I'm trying to read mail contents from this server
Mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
Mail.select('Inbox')

type, messages = Mail.search(None, 'ALL')
```

Error I'm gertting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user01/PycharmProjects/MongoAlchemy/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    M = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL('ns21.interactivedns.com', 995)
  File "C:\Users\user01\PycharmProjects\MongoAlchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\imaplib2\imaplib2.py", line 2073, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, debug, debug_file, identifier, timeout, debug_buf_lvl)
  File "C:\Users\user01\PycharmProjects\MongoAlchemy\venv\lib\site-packages\imaplib2\imaplib2.py", line 392, in __init__
    raise self.error('unrecognised server welcome message: %s' % repr(self.welcome))
imaplib2.imaplib2.error: unrecognised server welcome message: None
```

Comment: Have you tried port 993? In your code you have 995 not the 993.

Comment: yes I tired. I got "authentication failed" error when used 993